# JSP compilation fails when using dynamic classpath generated by IntelliJ IDEA on Windows

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, javac

I have a Spring/MVC/Tomcat website project that I am attempting to run with IntelliJ IDEA. Because I am running on Windows, there is a command-line size limit, which is exceeded by the large classpath. I use IntelliJ's dynamic classpath feature which puts the classpath in a jar file to shorten the command line. `Java` runs with `-classpath <classpath.jar>`.

When I try to view a page, the JSP compilation fails with an error to this effect:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [<removed>.java]
    [javac] <removed>.java:11: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.*;
    [javac] ^
```

I ran it in debug and stepped into where the java compilation was being done and found the `javac` command line used. It was put together in `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal`. I ran the `javac` command myself, with `-verbose`, and noticed that the dependency path from the `search path for class files:` log line shows up like:

```
C:\Users\<removed>\AppData\Local\Temp\file:\C:\Users\<removed>\lib\servlet-api-3.0.jar
```

Note that it seems like the absolute URI path is being treated as a relative path, resulting in an invalid path. I believe this is why it's not compiling properly.

Intellij's generated pathing jar's `MANIFEST.MF` lists the classpath with entries that are absolute paths that look like:

```
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/charsets.jar file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/deploy.jar [...]
```

This problem doesn't happen on Mac, using dynamic classpath jar (even though it's not necessary because the command line too long error does not happen) so I believe something about the Windows path or the way that IntelliJ generates the classpath jar on Windows is messing up the JSP compilation.

Also, using an Ant build task that generates a pathing jar with relative paths works too, but I am interested in avoiding the use of Ant here.

How can I get this working, or what else do I need to investigate to get to the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug in JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8030046).

Javac incorrectly handles absolute paths in manifest classpath headers. It has been fixed in JDK9.

Answer (score 0):

When I investigated this problem, assuming Java8, I found a different root cause in my case.

### In short:

- The "/org/apache/jasper/servlet/TldScanner.java" on Line 102, attempts    to scan locations for potential JARs.
- It uses the "/org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanner.java" to actually search.
- Put a breakpoint on Line 221 `URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)    classLoader).getURLs();`
- You will see this ClassLoader has the "classpath.jar" as a potential JAR to scan (i.e. process).
- But it cannot further find JARs referenced by a (classpath.jar) JAR's manifest file.  Meaning, the real JAR(s) you need are not going to be checked.

### A short fix, a for this is to:

- Add "standard-1.1.2.jar" to your web/WEB-INF/lib/ dir.
- If you look inside this jar, you will see *.tld files.

### Test:

- You can put a breakpoint on TldScanner.java Line 311 `found = true;`.
- When it is not working, you will never hit this line.
- When it works, with this (or any) fix, it will hit this line.

Comment: I don't see the ClassLoader having my classpath jar as a potential JAR to scan